# Converting numeric data stored as character to numeric in SAS

Tags: formatting, sas

I'm trying to pull data stored as $24. I want to convert it from character to numeric. The input(variable-name,comma24.) function is not working for me. A sample of the data is given below.

5.35
5.78
413,000
3,280,000
5.97
6.72
5
6.53
6
4.59
4.25
5
6.38
6.41
4.1
6.56
5.45
6.07
4.28
5.54
5.87
3.88
5.53
5.65
6.47
207,000
4,935,000
4,400,000
6,765,000
2,856,000
53,690,000

Comment: Have you tried `comma24.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your code, but for some reason I could get it work when the reading and conversion were in different data steps, but not when it was the same data step.

The following works just fine:

```
DATA one;
  INPUT y: $24. @@;
DATALINES;
5.35 5.78 413,000 3,280,000 5.97
RUN;

DATA one;
  SET one;
  z = INPUT(y, comma24.);
RUN;
```

However if I put the calculation of `z` in the first data step, I was getting missing values without any error message. I have no explanation for this behavior, but hopefully the workaround will work for you as well.

Comment: FWIW, putting conversion in the first data step (*after* the first input statement) works fine for me; SAS 9.2M3 / Windows.